# Nested Route not working on React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a simple tree of routes, with a single nested route not working:

```
import React from 'react'
import Main from './Folders/Main'
import Create from './Folders/Create'
import {Outlet, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

const RenderFolders = () => (
  <div>
    <div>Folders</div>
    <Outlet />
  </div>
)

const App = () => {
  return [
    <Route index element={<Main />} />,
    <Route path="create" element={<Create />} />,
    <Route path="folders" element={<RenderFolders />}>
      <Route index element={<Main />} />
      <Route path="create" element={<Create />} />
    </Route>,
    <Route path="*" element={<div>Not Found</div>} />
  ]
}
export default App
```

The routes work like this:

- localhost:8082/ -> `<Main />`
- localhost:8082/create -> `<Create />`
- localhost:8082/folders -> `<RenderFolders><Main /></RenderFolders>`
- localhost:8082/folders/create -> Nothing, blank
- localhost:8082/test -> `<div>Not Found</div>`

`/folders/create` is not rendering anything

Also, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Routes and routed components are rendering without issue here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-route-not-working-on-react-router-v6-u3foby). I suspect there's no issue with the routes and you've an issue in one of those routed components, i.e. `Create`. Can you edit post to include all relevant code in a [mcve]? Feel free to also fork my sandbox and add in more of your code there to see if you can reproduce the issue and then we can inspect and debug it live. Can you also let us know how you are running the app? What are the reproduction steps to produce the errors?

Comment: Maybe also try ***not*** rendering all the routes in an array like that. At a minimum it should eliminate a React missing key warning. Just render them like normal into the `Routes` component.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, the problem was a webpack.config.js parameter:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'web',
  devServer: {port: 8082, historyApiFallback: true},
  output: {
    publicPath: '/'     <----
  },
}
```

output.publicPath was commented due to this App is a MicroFrontEnd implementation. I'll try another way.